# QPX Express API 400 error - Invalid inputs: received empty request

Tags: json, coldfusion

I have searched far and wide. I'm not a JSON fundi in the least, so please help if you can.

I am using the QPX API with Coldfusion and trying to do a simple request and return the results.

What I have so far is the following:

```
<cfset qpxFields ='
{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": "1"
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "SFO",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "2014-09-19"
      }
    ],
    "solutions": "1"
  }
}'>



<cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=YOUR_KEY" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(qpxFields)#">
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>
#httpResp.FileContent#
</cfoutput>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest", "message": "Invalid inputs: received empty request." } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid inputs: received empty request." } }
```

If I output the variable qpxFields I get:

```
{ "request": { "passengers": { "adultCount": "1" }, "slice": [ { "origin": "SFO", "destination": "LAX", "date": "2014-09-19" } ], "solutions": "1" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The variable qpxFields should not be in quotes.

```
<cfset qpxFields = {
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": "1"
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "SFO",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "2014-09-19"
      }
    ],
    "solutions": "1"
  }
} />



<cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=YOUR_KEY" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(qpxFields)#">
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>
#httpResp.FileContent#
</cfoutput>
```